# Issue when adding double type variables from an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public  void dataAnalytics()
{
  double sum=0;  

    System.out.println("dataAnalytics for the Rural region");

    for (Record ee :RList)
    {
       sum=sum+RList.get(4);
    }
}
```

I have a very simple problem here , i am a novice java programmer , so please do be easy with me. I have an arrayLisl "Rlist" which has income in 4th index. What i am trying to accomplish is to get the sum of all income elements in the arraylist. I have tried sum=sum+RList.get(4); but i does not seem to work .
income is initialized as double  inthe super class but is passed in the arraylist constructor as string.

Comment: How is your ArrayList defined?

Comment: First of all, the 4th index? What do you mean? The first index for Lists is 0, so your 4th index may be 3, not 4 (perhaps you already know this). Second, you're not using the Record variable ee at all. Why do you bother in making a for loop? Third, I don't understand your explanation on how "income" is initialized. Can you add some more code on that part?

Comment: the reason for the loop is to go through each record inthe RList and retrieve the income element , and subsequently get a sum of all the income elements in the list.

Comment: for (Record ee :RList)
    sum=sum+Double.valueOf(ee.getIncome());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the use of `ee` in the loop? It is unused there.
Assuming you have an arraylist of `Record` objects and you are able to
access their *income* fields via a **getter method** like `getIncome()` which returns a string, you should do that:

```
for(Record ee :RList)
    sum = sum + Double.valueOf(ee.getIncome());
```

Comment: sure , im just waiting for the timer to reset :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have stored income as a String in your ArrayList, then you must convert the String to a  double type before attempting to add it to another double.

See Double.parseDouble http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html